# How to programmatically run commands from the Chrome Command Menu

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I'd like to be able to programmatically call commands from the [Chrome Dev Tools Command Menu](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/command-menu). I tried searching through Chrome APIs and Chrome Extension docs, but I didn't see anything that mentioned this.

Is there a way to programmatically run these commands?

Comment: Extensions can use [these commands](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/) via `chrome.debugger` API.

Comment: Extensions and automation tools like Puppeteer/Selenium can use [CDP commands](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/) via [chrome.debugger](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger) API.